# No entiendo porque salen estos valores

Tags: c#

```
int i = 2;
int j = 3;
int x = j = ++i * j++;
```

No entiendo porque i es igual a 3 después de ejecutarlo todo y j sigue valiendo 3 en vez de 4. Gracias de antemano si me respondes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Operador de incremento ++

El operador de incremento unario ++ incrementa su operando en 1. El operando debe ser una variable, un acceso de propiedad o un acceso de indexador.

El operador de incremento se admite en dos formas: el operador de incremento posfijo (x++) y el operador de incremento prefijo (++x).

### Operador de incremento de postfijo

El resultado de x++ es el valor de `x antes de la operación`, tal y como se muestra en el ejemplo siguiente:

```
int i = 3;
Console.WriteLine(i);   // output: 3
Console.WriteLine(i++); // output: 3
Console.WriteLine(i);   // output: 4
```

### Operador de incremento prefijo

El resultado de ++x es el valor de `x después de la operación`, tal y como se muestra en el ejemplo siguiente:

```
double a = 1.5;
Console.WriteLine(a);   // output: 1.5
Console.WriteLine(++a); // output: 2.5
Console.WriteLine(a);   // output: 2.5
```

Documentación oficial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators

Comment: Muchas gracias fredyfx, muy buena la explicación.

Comment: Gracias, solo hice referencia a la documentación oficial. Considera en marcar esta respuesta como aceptada para mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas).

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que hay un error con lo que pones, j vale 9

```
int i = 2;
int j = 3;
int x = j = ++i * j++;

Console.WriteLine(x); // 9
Console.WriteLine(j); // 9
Console.WriteLine(i); // 3
```

Quizás quisiste poner

```
int i = 2;
int j = 3;
int x = ++i * j++;

Console.WriteLine(x); // 9
Console.WriteLine(j); // 4
Console.WriteLine(i); // 3
```

Para entender, creo que es mejor descomponer la situación

```
int x = ++i;

//Es lo mismo que:

i = i + 1;
int x = i;
```

En cambio

```
int x = i++;
//Es lo mismo que:
int x = i;
i = i + 1;
```

Entonces en int x = ++i * j++, El equivalente es:

```
int i = 2;
int j = 3;

i = i + 1; // i = 3
int x = i * j; // 3 * 3
j = j + 1; // j = 4
```

Comment: Si, perdón para que entiendas mejor quería decir que x será 9, j también y la "i" será 4. La cosa es ¿porqué j no es igual a 10? porque ¿j se queda con el resultado de la multiplicación y no con el incremento?. El código sería así int x = j = ++i * j++;

Comment: @Jesucrito Porque esa expresión es una reducción, una abreviación de lo que realmente pasa. Esa expresión es lo mismo que te puse en el último trozo de código. Hace muchos años cuando solo existían for y where, a alguien se le ocurrió abreviar sumar 1 (antes y después) a una variable

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias.